# Have to Double Click Links in Angular App To Fire Off Function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-ng-if

I'm working on an angular app right now, and I've got a navbar with `<a>` tagged links. Every time I click on one of those links, I want to have a flag variable be toggled, so that I can hide the navbar, and show another component.

Right now, I'm viewing my site on Chrome, and I have to click the link 2 times for the toggle function to fire. Here's the html code below.

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="padding-top:0" *ngIf="showFlag === true">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <!-- <p>{{showFlag}}</p> -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav" id="link-nav" style="width:30%">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <span>
            <a class="nav-link" (click)="toggleComponent()">My Story</a>
            <hr>
          </span>
        </li>
```

The above snippet is how I thought I could toggle between showing and hiding this jumbotron.
Something to note is that this component is called `header` and it is nested inside another component. I don't know if that could be why I have to double click a link...
The structure looks like this:

```
<div id="particles-js">
    <app-header></app-header>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Since you're using the <a> tag, you still have to give it an href attribute (ie href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: Thanks @rrd. Um I just added the href in and I still have this double clicking issue...

Comment: can you make a stackblitz with this example :) ?

Comment: @Alann I tried to make a basic stackblitz for this example. Its here. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-roue5m) This issue doesn't occur on the stackblitz code. Its going to take a bit of effort to get it there too. 

I've a hunch that this issue might be because I've nested this component inside another, and the parent of this might be like an overlay? Or is it just me thinking that

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be in the CSS for the container of this markup.

I'd added `position:fixed;` to the CSS, and this made it have this kinda overlay effect.

Removing it fixed the issue.